# Google says an indexed page is not in the sitemap even though it is in the sitemap

Tags: google

Search Console of google shows my website is "indexed but not submitted in sitemap". However, I have submitted the URL in site map. It's been so long.

I have tested for `https://www.example.com/annapurna-base-camp-trekking` which is in sitemap but Google says its not.

Is it the reason my website is not in top list?

[image]

Comment: How long is “so long”? And has your sitemap definitely been submitted in Search Console?

Answer (score 1):

That could happen if the URL you're testing is formatted even slightly differently than it is in the xml sitemap. For example, it could be that the version you're testing does not have a trailing slash but the version in the sitemap does. The good news is it's indexed though!

Comment: Other possible differences: `http` vs `https`, `www` vs `no-www` or even capitalization.

Comment: The URL in their sitemap is exactly the same as the one shown in the screenshot.